# Display: table эмуляция в jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Нужно чтобы все внутренние элементы divа имели такую ширину чтобы занимали 100% ширины внешнего дива, как сделать без table и table-cell?

http://jsfiddle.net/mjGts/

Comment: [Такой вариант][1] подойдет?

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/mjGts/2/

Comment: Не подходит, потому что если будет контента побольше внутри то внутренний див должен расширятся... Они не должны быть равны.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386742/make-a-grid-fluid-layout-just-like-old-tables-but-with-divs-css-jquery